# "OCR running error" when using MODI 2003 with C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, ocr, modi

I've been struggling to get MODI to work properly at all today.  Here's the code I'm attempting to use (adapted from the VB given at the Wikipedia entry for [MODI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Document_Imaging).

```
private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string inputFile = @"C:\testImage.bmp";
    textBox1.Text = GetTextFromImage( inputFile );
}

private string GetTextFromImage( string fileName )
{
    string output = "";
    var doc1 = new MODI.Document();
    doc1.Create( fileName );
    doc1.OCR( MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false );

    for ( int i = 0; i < doc1.Images.Count; i++ )
    {
        output += doc1.Images[i].Layout.Text;
    }

    doc1.Close();
    return output;
}
```

When I execute this, I get an error on the OCR() line saying the following:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandledMessage=OCR running error Source="" ErrorCode=-959967087
```

Now, I looked up that error code and found another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130473/net-ocring-an-image) in which they found that they couldn't run the OCR on small images, but the one in question is `1700`x`2338`, which should be plenty large enough for the cause.

Does anyone have any advice on where to go next with this?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the MODI failures may be cumulative; however through varying investigation it looks as though it may be tied to the DPI. Modifying the `PixelFormat`, clearing the background, adjusting the raw image size, and adjusting the `OCROrientImage` and `OCRStraightenImage` flags had no effect.

What worked for me was modifying the DPI of the written `Bitmap` for both horizontal and vertical to 300. The default for a `Bitmap` is 96 and in working with a specific image that did work I noted the DPI was set at 300.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and the terribly unhelpful error message seems to be generated when MODI is unable to OCR the bitmap. 
The solution I came up with is:

1 - Create your bitmap in either of these two formats
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
or
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555

2 - Clear the background of the bitmap to white and then copy your text "picture" to the middle of it and then do the MODI.Document.Create (......

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem on code. Just update office 2003 service pack 3. Here is the link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8

It will work fine....

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Change your code to this:

```
doc1.OCR;
```

And let the engine decide its own language.

Comment: this causes bad language error when you have charachters with smaller fontsize than 10..