# How to OCR serially with MODI (Microsoft Office Document Imaging) in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, ms-office, ocr, modi

I have documents scanned as .jpg pictures in a folder and I would like to do OCR in C# serially for each of my documents in that folder.
so far ive done this :

```
public string CheckFilesAndDoOCR(string directoryPath)
{
    directoryPath = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures + "\\OCRTempPictures\\";
    IEnumerator files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();
    string TheTxt = "";

    while (files.MoveNext())
    {
        // FileInfo
        FileInfo nfo = new FileInfo(Convert.ToString(files.Current));

        // Get new file name
        string fileName = AlltoJPG(nfo);

        // FileInfo (New File)
        FileInfo foo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        // Check for JPG File Format
        if (foo.Extension == ".jpg" || foo.Extension == ".JPG")
        // or // ImageFormat.Jpeg.ToString()
        {
            try
            {
                // OCR Operations...
                MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
                md.Create(foo.FullName);
                md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false); // OCR();
                MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
                TheTxt = image.Layout.Text;
                md.Close(false);

                // Create text file with the same Image file name
                FileStream createFile = new FileStream(foo.DirectoryName + "\\" + foo.Name.Replace(foo.Extension,string.Empty) + ".txt", FileMode.CreateNew);

                // Save the image text in the text file
                StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(createFile);
                writeFile.Write(TheTxt);
                writeFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Expected errors
                string LogPath = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures + "\\OCRTempPictures\\OCRInfo.txt";
                Logger(LogPath, "| Exception: Source[" + ex.Source + "] Message[" + ex.Message + "] InnerException[" + ex.InnerException + "] StackTrace[" + ex.StackTrace + "] | ");
                // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "OCR Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
    return TheTxt;
}
```

but MODI gives the `OCR running!` or `Cant reach file.File is in use.` errors..

**Depending on the situation:**

- How can I avoid these error?
- Is there anyways to stop OCR action and deplete all objects in use?

If anyone can answer any of the questions above it would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699740/ocr-running-error-when-using-modi-2003-with-c-sharp This is a generic error which means that MODI has trouble recognizing the bitmap

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i did! but those answers doesnt solves my issue.. it recognizes all characters and im using jpeg files and also after working on it for a real long time i found out most of the issues but still most crazy issue exists. Its not letting me move-delete that file that i had the ocr results. idk why it does that. says the file still being used. ill update question.

Comment: The reason you are getting this error is because you are attempting to process multiple images at once.  Implement code to prevent this.

Comment: @Ramhound ahh crap! you are right. i dont know how much i can thank to you! You should post that as an answer so i can give you the rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fully working code! thanks to @Ramhound

Below code just specifies a folder full of pictures and one by one does OCR scan on them.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all images inside a Folder
    /// and triggers OCR on each..
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="directoryPath"> Path to Folder </param>
    /// <returns> Text </returns>        
    public string CheckFileAndDoOCR(string directoryPath)
    {
        string TheTxt = "";
        IEnumerator files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();

        while (files.MoveNext())
        {
            // FileInfo
            FileInfo foo = new FileInfo(Convert.ToString(files.Current));

            // Check for JPG File Format
            if (foo.Extension == ".jpg" || foo.Extension == ".JPG")
            // or // ImageFormat.Jpeg.ToString()
            {
                // Start OCR Procedure
                TheTxt = DoOCR(foo.FullName);
                // Create TXT file next to ImageFile
                string txtFileName = foo.DirectoryName + "\\" + foo.Name.Replace(foo.Extension,"") + ".txt";
                FileStream createFile = new FileStream(txtFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                // Save the text in to TXT file
                StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(createFile);
                writeFile.Write(TheTxt);
                // Close
                writeFile.Close();
                createFile.Close();
            }

            // Delete used pictures (Optional)
            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            try 
            { foo.Delete(); }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Logger(LogPath, "| Exception: Source[" + ex.Source + "] Message[" + ex.Message + 
                "] InnerException[" + ex.InnerException + "] StackTrace[" + ex.StackTrace + "] | "); }
            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        }
        return TheTxt;
    }
    // DoOCR
    // 
    /// <summary>
    /// Start an OCR scan on given ImageFile
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FullPath"> Path to ImageFile </param>
    /// <returns> Text </returns>
    public string DoOCR(string FullPath)
    {
        string txt;

        // OCR Operations...
        MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document(); // Create MODI.Document
        md.Create(FullPath); // Fill MODI.Document with my file
        // Showprogress of OCR
        md.OnOCRProgress += new MODI._IDocumentEvents_OnOCRProgressEventHandler(this.ShowProgress);
        // Begin OCR
        md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false); // OCR();
        // Image from file
        MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
        txt = image.Layout.Text;
        // Optionally you can get only first word by using word.Text
        /// Words from Image :
        // MODI.Word word = image.Layout.Words[0];
        /// Text from first Word :
        // txt = word.Text;

        // Close OCR
        word = null;
        image = null;
        md.Close(false);
        md = null;

        // Finalize
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        // Return Text
        return txt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Doc1.OCR() check for multi-page tiff file if you insert only single page file then it will shows that error try using multi-page tiff file